# Populate select field form data from MySQL database and select the right value

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I already have a database query that shows the text inputs, but after an hour of fiddling with the code I still can't figure out how to correctly display select fields and their correct selected options. The selected option is shown now as an extra field which is the incorrect way of doing this.

I want to show the selected options for accounttype and credittype, which are also in the users table but I just don't know how to implement it with my current code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
    <?php $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users");
echo "<table style='width:650px'>";
echo "<tr style='color:#CC0000'><td>ID</td><td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Phone</td><td>Email</td><td>Account Type</td><td>Credit Type</td><td>Credit</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . "<input id='password' type='password' name='password' placeholder='*****'  style='width:80px' />" . "</td><td><input id='phone' type='text' name='phone' value='".$row['phone']."' style='width:100px' /></td><td><input id='email' type='text' name='email' value='".$row['email']."' style='width:100px' /></td><td><select id='accounttype' name='accounttype' style='width:125px' /><option>".$row['accounttype']."</option><option>Agency</option><option>Admin</option><option>Super Admin</option></select></td><td><select id='credittype' name='credittype' style='width:125px' /><option>".$row['credittype']."</option><option>Flexible</option><option>Strict</option><option>Unlimited</option></select></td><td><input id='credit' type='text' name='credit' value='".$row['credit']."' style='width:50px' /></td></tr>";

      } 
       echo "</table>";
       ?>
```

Comment: You have to use "selected" attribute to select it by default.e.g. `<option selected>$row['credittype']</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it myself, maybe not the cleanest of codes but it works:

```
    <?php $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users");
echo "<table style='width:650px;text-align: center'>";
echo "<tr style='color:#CC0000'><td>ID</td><td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Phone</td><td>Email</td><td>Account Type</td><td>Credit Type</td><td>Credit</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . "<input id='password' type='password' name='password' placeholder='*****'  style='width:80px' />" . "</td><td><input id='phone' type='text' name='phone' value='".$row['phone']."' style='width:95px' /></td><td><input id='email' type='text' name='email' value='".$row['email']."' style='width:100px' /></td><td><select id='accounttype' name='accounttype' style='width:115px' /><option"; if ($row['accounttype'] == 'Agency') echo " selected";echo ">Agency</option><option"; if ($row['accounttype'] == 'Admin') echo " selected";echo ">Admin</option><option"; if ($row['accounttype'] == 'Super Admin') echo " selected";echo ">Super Admin</option></select></td><td><select id='credittype' name='credittype' style='width:105px' /><option"; if ($row['credittype'] == 'Flexible') echo " selected";echo ">Flexible</option><option"; if ($row['credittype'] == 'Strict') echo " selected";echo ">Strict</option><option"; if ($row['credittype'] == 'Unlimited') echo " selected";echo ">Unlimited</option></select></td><td><input id='credit' type='text' name='credit' value='".$row['credit']."' style='width:50px' /></td></tr>";

      } 
       echo "</table>";
       ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of selecting the right option is `<option selected>value</option>`. Loop over the values and add the selected attribute.